# deploy mvc5 on iis7

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, iis-7, asp.net-mvc-5, devops

After deploying an asp.net mvc 5 project on iis 7, and then click browse, i got a blank page!

Hint:
I've checked http static content, http redirection, and http errors.

Any ideas?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you see when you debug the application locally?

Comment: i can see home/index which is the default route while using iisexpress. but when i switched to use localiis i could see a blank page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The app. run after i run this command; which installed the asp.net on iis. 
Then recreated a virtual directory once again for the application on the local iis:
%windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regiis.exe -ir

Answer (score 1):

To fix IIS mappings for ASP.NET, run the Aspnet_regiis.exe utility.
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/306005

Answer (score 0):

One idea: your default page is blank.

If there is an existing index.html in root it might be showing that. Can you delete all content from server and deploy again?